Projection onto $\kappa$-strategically closed forcings
Let $P$ be a forcing, $\alpha$ an ordinal. The game $G_\alpha(P)$ of length $\alpha$ is played as follows: Players I and II alternate writing down a sequence $p_0\geq p_1\geq\ldots\geq p_i\geq\ldots$ of descending conditions in $P$. Player I plays $p_i\in P$ for odd $i\in \alpha$, and Player II plays $p_i\in P$ for even and limit $i\in \alpha$. Player II wins if it can always move before the game ends. $P$ is said to be $\alpha$-strategically closed if Player II has a winning strategy for $G_\alpha(P)$.
It is well-known that the standard forcing $\mathbb{S}_\kappa$ that shoots a $\square_\kappa$-sequence is $(\kappa+1)$-strategically closed.
Let $P,Q$ be forcings. $\pi:Q\to P$ is said to be a projection if $\pi(1_Q)=1_P$, $q'\leq q\to \pi(q')\leq \pi(q)$, and if $p\leq \pi(q)$, then there is $q'\leq q$ such that $\pi(q')\leq p$. If $\pi:Q\to P$ is a projection, then any $Q$-generic contains a $P$-generic.
I have a proof for the following assertion:

Let $\kappa,\lambda$ be cardinals. If $P$ is a $\kappa$-strategically closed forcing of size $\leq\lambda$, then $\mathrm{Col}(\kappa,\lambda)$ projects onto $P$.

However, this cannot be, because PFA is preserved by $\omega_2$-closed forcings, while PFA implies $\neg\square_\kappa$ for all $\kappa$. So for $\kappa=\omega_2$ and large enough $\lambda$, $\mathrm{Col}(\omega_2,\lambda)$ projects onto $\mathbb{S}_{\omega_2}$ and forcing by $\mathrm{Col}(\omega_2,\lambda)$ adds a $\square_{\omega_2}$-sequence, which then contradicts PFA if PFA holds in the ground model. So what's going wrong?
Here is the proof for the assertion:
We may assume $\mathrm{Col}(\kappa,\lambda)=\{ s:\alpha\to \lambda\mid \alpha<\kappa\}$. Let $P$ be $\kappa$-strategically closed and let $S_\kappa$ be Player II's winning strategy in $G_\kappa(P)$. We define $\pi:\mathrm{Col}(\kappa,\lambda)\to P$ by induction on $\alpha<\kappa$ so that for each $s\in \mathrm{Col}(\kappa,\lambda)$ and $i<\mathrm{dom}(s)$, $\pi(s\upharpoonright i)$ is an element that Player II has played in a partial play of the game. Let $\pi(0)=1_P$; each game initiates with Player II playing $p_0=1_P$. If $s\in \mathrm{Col}(\kappa,\lambda)$ and $\pi(s)$ has been defined as the final element of the partial play $\langle p_\alpha\mid \alpha\leq 2\cdot\eta\rangle$, for each $p\leq \pi(s)$, Player I extends the play by playing $p_{2\cdot\eta+1}=p$, and then Player II responds $p_{2\cdot \eta+2}$ according to the strategy $S_\kappa$. There are at most $\lambda$ elements that Player I can play, so there are at most $\lambda$ responses by Player II. Let $f$ be a surjection from $\lambda$ to the set of Player II's responses. Then set $\pi(s^\frown i)=f(i)$. 
Suppose $s\in \mathrm{Col}(\kappa,\lambda)$ has $\mathrm{dom}(s)=\alpha$ a limit and for all $i<\alpha$, $\pi(s\upharpoonright i)$ is defined as elements played by Player II in a partial play. Since Player II has followed $S_\kappa$ in the play, it is able to play a lower bound of $\langle \pi(s\upharpoonright i)\mid i<\alpha\rangle$ in $P$, according to $S_\kappa$. Set $\pi(s)$ to be that lower bound.

EDIT: The below works only for the poset $\mathbb{S}_{\omega_1}$. I have added an additional argument for the poset $\mathbb{S}_{\kappa}$ for $\kappa>\omega_1$.
There is a very subtle difference between $(\kappa+1)$-strategic closure and $\kappa^+$-strategic closure (let me point out that $(\kappa+1)$-strategic closure is equivalent to $\alpha$-strategic closure for all $\alpha<\kappa^+$). As you correctly note, the completeness player has a winning strategy in $G_{\omega_1+1}(\mathbb{S}_{\omega_1})$. However, they do not have one in $G_{\omega_2}(\mathbb{S}_{\omega_1})$ (at least if $\square_{\omega_1}$ fails in the ground model). The reason is simply because this would allow one to, from an $\mathbb{S}_{\omega_1}$-name for a square sequence, construct such a sequence already in $V$ (see also example 6.6 in Cummings' chapter in the handbook of set theory). Your proof needs the assumption that $P$ is $\kappa$-strategically closed and not merely $\alpha$-strategically closed for all $\alpha<\kappa$, so in general there is no projection from $\operatorname{Coll}(\omega_2,\lambda)$ onto the $\omega_1+1$-strategically closed poset $\mathbb{S}_{\omega_1}$.
For $\mathbb{S}_{\kappa}$ for $\kappa>\omega_1$, there is a different argument. In this case, by Lemma 6.9 in ``Squares, Scales and Stationary Reflection'' there is a poset $\mathbb{T}_{\gamma}$ for any $\gamma\leq\kappa$ such that $\mathbb{S}_{\kappa}*\mathbb{T}_{\gamma}$ has a $\gamma$-closed dense subset. Ergo there is a projection from an $\omega_2$-closed forcing (or its equivalent) onto $\mathbb{S}_{\kappa}$. The reason this does not cause any problems is that the poset $\mathbb{T}_{\gamma}$ threads the square-sequence added by $\mathbb{S}_{\kappa}$ so that $\square_{\omega_2}$ does not hold in the extension by $\mathbb{S}_{\kappa}*\mathbb{T}_{\gamma}$ (which preserves $\operatorname{PFA}$), although it does hold in an intermediate model.

But $\mathbb{S}{\omega_2}$ is $(\omega_2+1)$-strategically closed hence $\omega_2$-strategically closed. And in the proof, I don't think I need to require that $P$ be $\kappa^+$-strategically closed; Player II only needs a strategy for $G\kappa(P)$.

In fact from the PFA-preservation theorem, there is no $\omega_2$-closed forcing that can project onto $\mu$-strategically closed forcings for any $\mu>\omega$, so I think the problem is not at the numbers.

You're right, i confused the parameters. I have added a new argument which should work for the case you mention.

Oh I see, so the problem is that $Q$ projecting onto $P$ does not mean that if $V^P\models \phi$ then $V^Q\models \phi$.
